# fgetc(): Reading and storing a string of unknown length

Tags: c

What I need to do for an assignment is:

- open a file (using fopen())
- read the name of a student (using fgetc())
- store that name in some part of a struct

The problem I have is that I need to read an arbitrary long string into name, and I don't know how to store that string without wasting memory (or writing into non-allocated memory).

**EDIT**

My first idea was to allocate a 1 byte (char) memory block, then call realloc() if more bytes are needed but this doesn't seem very efficient. Or maybe I could double the array if it is full and then at the end copy the chars into a new block of memory of the exact size.

Comment: Your edit suggestion of realloc to double the size seems fine to me. You could start with an array that's probably big enough (given you know it's a student name) and avoid the realloc most of the time. Mr Supercalifragilisticsuperalidoscious Antidisestablishmentarianism doesn't go to your school.

Comment: @Paul- You _sure_ he doesn't?

Comment: You don't need to copy the characters into a new memory of exactly the right size - you can just use `realloc()` once more at the end to trim the allocated block down to the right size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't** worry about wasting 100 or 1000 bytes which is likely to be long enough for all names.
I'd probably just put the buffer that you're reading into on the stack.

**Do** worry about writing over the end of the buffer.  i.e. buffer overrun.  Program to prevent that!

When you come to store the name into your structure you can malloc a buffer to store the name the exact length you need (don't forget to add an extra byte for the null terminator).

But if you really must store names of any length at all then you could do it with realloc.
i.e. Allocate a buffer with malloc of some size say 50 bytes.

Then when you need more space, use realloc to increase it's length.  Increase the length in blocks of say 50 bytes and keep track with an int on how big it is so that you know when you need to grow it again.  At some point, you will have to decide how long that buffer is going to be, because it can't grow indefinitely.

Comment: you really should worry about buffer overrun unless you are dealing with the quickest and dirties test application, or can be absolutely sure the string can't be larger than your buffer

Answer (score 2):

You could read the string character by character until you find the end, then rewind to the beginning, allocate a buffer of the right size, and re-read it into that, but unless you are on a tiny embedded system this is probably silly.  For one thing, the fgetc, fread, etc functions create buffers in the O/S anyway.

You could allocate a temporary buffer that's large enough, use a length limited read (for safety) into that, and then allocate a buffer of the precise size to copy it into.  You probably want to allocate the temporary buffer on the stack rather than via malloc, unless you think it might exceed your available stack space.

If you are writing single threaded code for a tiny system you can allocate a scratch buffer on startup or statically, and re-use it for many purposes - but be really carefully your usage can't overlap!

Given the implementation complexity of most systems, unless you really research how things work it's entirely possible to write memory optimized code that actually takes more memory than doing things the easy way.  Variable initializations can be another surprisingly wasteful one.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to allocate a buffer of sufficient size:

```
char name_buffer [ 80 ];
```

Generally, most names (at least common English names) will be less than 80 characters in size. If you feel that you may need more space than that, by all means allocate more.

Keep a counter variable to know how many characters you have already read into your buffer:

```
int chars_read = 0; /* most compilers will init to 0 for you, but always good to be explicit */
```

At this point, read character by character with `fgetc()` until you either hit the end of file marker or read 80 characters (79 really, since you need room for the null terminator). Store each character you've read into your buffer, incrementing your counter variable.

```
while ( ( chars_read < 80 ) && ( !feof( stdin ) ) ) {
  name_buffer [ chars_read ] = fgetc ( stdin );
  chars_read++;
}
if ( chars_read < 80 )
  name_buffer [ chars_read ] = '\0'; /* terminating null character */
```

I am assuming here that you are reading from `stdin`. A more complete example would also check for errors, verify that the character you read from the stream is valid for a person's name (no numbers, for example), etc. If you try to read more data than for which you allocated space, print an error message to the console.

I understand wanting to maintain as small a buffer as possible and only allocate what you need, but part of learning how to program is understanding the trade-offs in code/data size, efficiency, and code readability. You can `malloc` and `realloc`, but it makes the code much more complex than necessary, and it introduces places where errors may come in - NULL pointers, array index out-of-bounds errors, etc. For most practical cases, allocate what should suffice for your data requirements plus a small amount of breathing room. If you find that you are encountering a lot of cases where the data exceeds the size of your buffer, adjust your buffer to accommodate it - that is what debugging and test cases are for.